# Like query with prepared statement

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

```scala
val term="govind"
SQL("SELECT id,name FROM acc WHERE name like '%"+term+"%'") //works
```

but

```
SQL("SELECT id,name FROM acc WHERE name like '%{term}%'").on("term"->term) // doesn't works
```

How i convert the first query to prepared statement that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include % in the 'term' value.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, we can include the % wildcards in the SQL text, and combine those with the bind parameter, using the MySQL `CONCAT` function, for example:

```
SQL("SELECT id,name FROM acc WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%',{term},'%'").on("term"->term)
```

Answer (score 0):

including `%` with `term` keyword works

```
SQL("SELECT id,name FROM acc WHERE name like {term}").on("term"->("%"+term+"%"))
```